# OOP ~ PHP, Different Function methods?

Tags: php

I have been reading over the manuals of a verity of different methods that can be used in a OOP Style development zone.

```
class Class{
    private function SortArrayByNoExample (){
            $ExampleArray = array ('Item_1', 'Item_3','Item_6','Item_5','Item_4','Item_2');
            Echo "Original Array: <br>";
            print_r($ExampleArray);
            Echo "<br><br><br>";
            echo "Sorted Array";
            natsort($ExampleArray);

            print_r($ExampleArray);
        }

        public function NaturalSort ($Arg1){
            if (!is_array($Arg1)){
                $this->SortArrayByNoExample();
            }else{
                natsort($Arg1);
                return $Arg1;
            }
}
```

I have this current scenario, take this as an example.

I understand public functions can be accessed by:

```
$Foo = new Class();
$Foo->PublicFunctionName();
```

and Private function can only be accessed from within the class.

```
    public function NaturalSort ($Arg1){
        if (!is_array($Arg1)){
            $this->SortArrayByNoExample();
        }
```

If these function perfectly on their own, why is their such methods as:

`Abstract`, `static`, `protected`.

Then there is extensions such as:

```
class AnotherClass extends Class {}
```

^^ Why have this? Why can't you include the functions inside your original class.

My Overall question, is why would I use `Abstract`, `Static`, `Protected`, and `extends`?

Comment: Read _any_ primer on OO programming... This question as it is is way to broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily understand why these things exist once you have more experience. You don't even need very much more experience.

For example the need for `extends` (subclassing) and thus all your other concepts is quite obvious once you consider this artificial example:

```
abstract class Animal {
    // there are no "animal objects", only specific kinds of animals
    // so this class is abstract
    function eat(){}  // animals all eat the same way
    // different animals move differently, so we can't implement "move"
    // however all animals move, so all subclasses must have a "move" method
    abstract function move()
    // (I'm straining things a bit here...)
    // No one can order an animal to sleep
    // An animal must sleep on its own
    protected function sleep(){}
    // note if this function were *private*, then the only the
    // Animal class code can call "sleep()", *not* any subclasses
    // Since a Dog and a Cat sleep at different times, we want them
    // to be able to decide when to call sleep(), too.
}

abstract class FourLeggedAnimal {
    // all four-legged animals move the same way
    // but "four-legged-animal" is still abstract
    function move() {}
}


class Dog extends FourLeggedAnimal {
    // only dogs bark
    function bark(){}
}

class Cat extends FourLeggedAnimal {
    // only cats meow
    function meow(){}
}
```

(BTW, you should default to `protected` rather than `private` when you need a "not-`public`" method. I've never found a need for `private` in PHP.)

Comment: This is a very informative answer. If I could award more than a +1 and an accept. I truly would. thankyou

Comment: @user2146021 did it for you. Nice answer